# How to free Structure containing dynamically allocated double pointer to another structure type?

Tags: c, graph

I have created a graph structure in C. The structural definition of the graph is given below.

```
typedef struct _GNODE_ {
    int nodeNumber;             // vertex/node number
    int adjNum;                 // number of adjacent nodes
    struct _GNODE_ **adjacent;  // array of pointers to adjacent nodes
} _GNODE_ ;

typedef struct _GRAPH_ {
    int vc;         // number of vertices
    char *name;     // graph name
    int **AM;       // adjacency matrix
    _GNODE_ **node; // array of pointer to each vertices
} _GRAPH_ ;
```

where **_GNODE_** is the structure of a node in the graph.

The function **readGraphFromTxt(char *fileName , _GRAPH_ *graph)** reads a text file containing the adjacency matrix of the graph and call another function called **createGraphFromAM(_GRAPH_ *graph)** to create a graph structure.

```
int readGraphFromTxt(char *filename , _GRAPH_ *graph){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    int vc;
    int **AM;
    char *gname;
    if(fp != NULL){
        char graphName[100];
        fgets(graphName, 99, fp );
        gname = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*101);
        strncpy(gname , graphName, 99);
        fgets(graphName, 99, fp );
        fscanf(fp , "%d\n" , &vc);
        AM = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int*) * vc);
        for(int i=0; i<vc; i++){
            AM[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * vc);
            if(fscanf(fp, "%s" , graphName) ==EOF)    break;
            for(int j=0; j<vc; j++){
                AM[i][j] = graphName[j] - '0';
            }
        }
    }
    if(AM != NULL) graph->AM = AM;
    if(gname != NULL )  graph->name = gname;
    graph->vc = vc;
    createGraphFromAM(graph);
    fclose(fp);
    return vc;
}

void createGraphFromAM(_GRAPH_ *graph) {
    graph->node = (_GNODE_ **)malloc(sizeof(_GNODE_) * graph->vc) ; // array of pointers to different nodes

    for (int i=0; i<graph->vc ; i++){
        graph->node[i] = (_GNODE_ *)malloc(sizeof(_GNODE_));
        graph->node[i]->adjNum=0;
        graph->node[i]->nodeNumber = i;     // node number
        graph->node[i]->adjacent = (_GNODE_ **)malloc(sizeof(_GNODE_)) ; // because allocating 0 byte is tricky
    }

    for (int i=0; i<graph->vc ; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<graph->vc ; j++){
            if(graph->AM[i][j]==1){     // check for adjacency between i and j
                graph->node[i]->adjNum++;   // if adjacent increment number of adjacent nodes number
                graph->node[i]->adjacent = (_GNODE_ **)realloc( graph->node[i]->adjacent , sizeof(_GNODE_) * (graph->node[i]->adjNum+1));   // reallocate the memory to hold new adjacent member
                graph->node[i]->adjacent[graph->node[i]->adjNum-1] = graph->node[j];    // points to another node
            }
        }
        graph->node[i]->adjacent[graph->node[i]->adjNum] = NULL; // set last adjacent node to NULL
    }
}
```

The function **freeGraph(_GRAPH_ *graph)** is supposed to de-allocate all the memory allocated to graph. **But while calling this function the programs runs into a SEGMENTATION FAULT**.

```
void freeGraph(_GRAPH_ *graph){
    // free graph
    for (int i=0; i<graph->vc; i++) {
        // free each node data
        printf("\nLoop: %d\n", i);
            // free each adjacent node
        for (int k=0; k<graph->node[i]->adjNum; k++){
            if(graph->node[i]->adjacent[k]!=NULL){
                free(graph->node[i]->adjacent[k]);
            }
        }
        if(graph->node[i]->adjacent!=NULL) {
            free(graph->node[i]->adjacent);
        }
        free(graph->node[i]);
    }
    free(graph->node);
    for(int i=0; i<graph->vc; i++)
        if(graph->AM[i]!=NULL) free(graph->AM[i]);
    free(graph->AM);
    free(graph->name);
    free(graph);
}
```

The function called **printAllGraphNodeNumber(const _GRAPH_ *graph)** which prints all the node number and their adjacent nodes number.

```
void printAllGraphNodeNumber(const _GRAPH_ *graph) {
    printf("NODES IN THE GRAPH: ");
    for (int i=0; i<graph->vc ; i++) {
        printf("\nNode Number : %d\n|----->  Adjacent Nodes: ",graph->node[i]->nodeNumber);
        for (int j=0; j<graph->node[i]->adjNum; j++){
            printf("%d , ", graph->node[i]->adjacent[j]->nodeNumber );
        }
    }
}
```

**The content of the sample file "Graph01.txt" is:** 
And the maximum number of vertices is : 20

```
one
AM
10
0100010011
1000110100
0000100001
0000000010
0110000100
1100000001
0000000001
0100100010
1001000101
1010011010
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: for each `malloc()`, you need to write a corresponding `free()`.  And you probably need to free things more or less in the reverse order of allocation, because you can't access memory once it has been freed (at least, not reliably).

Comment: But make sure you do not call `free` until you no longer need the memory you are freeing. Attempting to access memory after it has been freed will invoke *Undefined Behavior* (up to, and including a SegFault).

Comment: Also, note that names starting with an underscore and followed by another underscore or a capital letter are reserved for use by 'the implementation' (of the C compiler and library). You should not write code that creates such names if you need to ask questions like this — you aren't coding the implementation if you need to ask such questions. In fact, in general, it is simplest to avoid creating any names that start with an underscore. (See ISO/IEC 9899:2011 [§7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) for more details and precision — but it is tricky wording).

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler for this piece  of information. Next time I will keep this in mind. Can you please tell where I went wrong?

Comment: You mean you want to read and understand your code, at this time on a Friday night?  Hmmm…   Well, you're going to need to look at how badly things go wrong if you fail to open the file.  You free all sorts of uninitialized pointers, and close a null file stream pointer.  Unhappiness will ensue out of all proportion.  I'll poke at the rest, but no promises that I'm going to come with an answer, let alone _the_ answer.

Comment: `char graphName[100];
        fgets(graphName, 99, fp );` — that's silly, and it wastes a byte.  Specify `sizeof(graphName)` and not 99 or other magic numbers.

Comment: Reusing the variable `graphName` as a general purpose buffer is confusing.  Use a neutral name (`buffer` is quite good; so is `line`).  Also, please illustrate a minimal data file.  It's a pain working out what you're processing.  You seem to have a line after the graph name that you completely ignore.  Is that intentional?  Also, you include the newline in the graph name; is that really what you want?

Comment: Yes, @JonathanLeffler its intentional. The file contains some other information about graph in that line.

Comment: OK; please show a graph file.  Preferably a graph that's got a bigger than 10x10 adjacency matrix because I'm worried about the encoding.  Or maybe the size is meant to be small.  It isn't clear.  There's a lot of error checking omitted, so we can't tell what's expected from the errors that don't exist reporting what isn't expected.

Comment: Thanks for the graph file.  Consider reading about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  The input data is an important part of that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- I have included the sample file above.

Comment: Your line `graph->node = (_GNODE_ **)malloc(sizeof(_GNODE_) * graph->vc) ;` is wrong; you're allocating an array of `_GNODE_ *`.  However, you're safe — this over-allocates the space needed.

Comment: Your line `graph->node[i]->adjacent = (_GNODE_ **)realloc( graph->node[i]->adjacent , sizeof(_GNODE_) * (graph->node[i]->adjNum+1)); ` is hard to read.  You should never use the `oldptr = realloc(oldptr, newsize);` idiom (as you do here); it leaks memory if the reallocation fails.  Use: `newptr = realloc(oldptr, newsize); if (newptr == 0) { …handle error… } oldptr = newptr; oldsize = newsize;`  This keeps important data safe.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- I think I have a solution. I removed the piece of code in function `freeGraph()` commented as "free each adjacent node". Because these are the pointer to different nodes of the graph which are going to be freed at last by `free(graph->node[i])` . I checked using valgrind all memory allocs are freed. Definitely its not an optimal solution. But I think it solves the problem for me.

Comment: I was suspicious about that, but I haven't got around to fixing all the missing error messages.  I needed to understand what you're allocating — which is pretty complex.  If Valgrind gives you a clean bill of health, you should be OK to go.  (Note that increasing an array size by one while reallocating is generally not a good idea; it can lead to quadratic behaviour if the data has to be moved each time you add an item.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an adaptation of your code.  I've cleaned up many points that I made in the comments to the question.  In particular:

- The structure names are removed from the namespace reserved for the implementation.
- Operations are checked and errors are reported.
- If the file open fails, uninitialized pointers are not freed.
- If the file open fails, the code doesn't try to close the unopened file stream.
- Because failure to allocate exits the program, there are fewer checks for nullness.
- The code counts how many adjacent nodes there are in a row and allocates the correct space all at once, rather than allocating the array one element at a time.
- I've preserved the null terminator for the adjacency list, though it isn't really necessary.
- By default, the program reads from a file `data`.  You can override that by specifying the file to read on the command line.

I also modified the code so that `readGraphFromTxt()` returns an allocated pointer, so that `freeGraph()` can correctly free it.

The main fix is to ensure that each `malloc()` is freed once.  As you diagnosed, you were trying to free the nodes pointed at by the adjacency lists, which was incorrect behaviour.  Those nodes should be freed en masse since they were allocated en masse.

I've tidied up the printing (at least according to my standards).

I used the files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` available from [GitHub](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) to simplify the error reporting.  When error reporting is simple, it is less likely to be omitted.  I've cheated and used `assert()` in a couple of places instead od a formal error test and message.

#### Code

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stderr.h"

typedef struct Node
{
    int nodeNumber;
    int adjNum;
    struct Node **adjacent;
} Node;

typedef struct Graph
{
    int vc;
    char *name;
    int **AM;
    Node **node;
} Graph;

static void createGraphFromAM(Graph *graph);

static Graph *readGraphFromTxt(const char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == 0)
        err_syserr("failed to open file %s for reading\n", filename);
    Graph *graph = malloc(sizeof(*graph));
    if (graph == 0)
        err_syserr("failed to allocate %zu bytes\n", sizeof(*graph));
    char line[100];
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) == 0)
        err_error("premature EOF - no graph name\n");
    line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
    char *gname = strdup(line);
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) == 0)
        err_error("premature EOF - no auxilliary info\n");
    int vc = -1;
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &vc) != 1)
        err_error("format error: didn't get an integer\n");
    if (vc < 1 || vc > 20)
        err_error("size of graph out of control: %d\n", vc);

    int **AM = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * vc);
    if (AM == 0)
        err_syserr("failed to allocate %zu bytes\n", sizeof(int *) * vc);

    for (int i = 0; i < vc; i++)
    {
        AM[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * vc);
        if (AM[i] == 0)
            err_syserr("failed to allocate %zu bytes\n", sizeof(int) * vc);
        if (fscanf(fp, "%s", line) == EOF)
            err_error("premature EOF - not enough lines of data for the adjacency matrix\n");
        if (strlen(line) < (size_t)vc)
            err_error("Adjacency matrix line is too short (got [%s] (%zu); wanted %d)\n",
                      line, strlen(line), vc);
        for (int j = 0; j < vc; j++)
        {
            assert(line[j] == '0' || line[j] == '1');
            AM[i][j] = line[j] - '0';
        }
    }

    graph->AM = AM;
    graph->name = gname;
    graph->vc = vc;
    graph->node = 0;
    createGraphFromAM(graph);
    fclose(fp);
    return graph;
}

/* How many times does val appear in array arr of size num? */
static inline size_t val_count(size_t num, const int arr[num], int val)
{
    assert(arr != 0);
    size_t count = 0;
    for (const int *end = arr + num; arr < end; arr++)
    {
        if (*arr == val)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

static void createGraphFromAM(Graph *graph)
{
    graph->node = (Node **)malloc(sizeof(*graph->node) * graph->vc);
    if (graph->node == 0)
        err_syserr("failed to allocate %zu bytes\n", sizeof(*graph->node) * graph->vc);

    for (int i = 0; i < graph->vc; i++)
    {
        graph->node[i] = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if (graph->node[i] == 0)
            err_syserr("failed to allocate %zu bytes\n", sizeof(Node));
        graph->node[i]->adjNum = val_count(graph->vc, graph->AM[i], 1);
        graph->node[i]->nodeNumber = i;
        size_t adj_size = sizeof(Node *) * (graph->node[i]->adjNum + 1);
        graph->node[i]->adjacent = (Node **)malloc(adj_size);
        if (graph->node[i]->adjacent == 0)
            err_syserr("failed to allocate %zu bytes\n", adj_size);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < graph->vc; i++)
    {
        Node *node = graph->node[i];
        int adj = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < graph->vc; j++)
        {
            if (graph->AM[i][j] == 1)
                node->adjacent[adj++] = graph->node[j];
        }
        node->adjacent[node->adjNum] = NULL;
    }
}

static void freeGraph(Graph *graph)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < graph->vc; i++)
    {
        free(graph->node[i]->adjacent);
        free(graph->node[i]);
    }
    free(graph->node);

    for (int i = 0; i < graph->vc; i++)
        free(graph->AM[i]);
    free(graph->AM);

    free(graph->name);
    free(graph);
}

static void printAllGraphNodeNumber(const Graph *graph)
{
    assert(graph != 0);
    printf("Nodes in the graph %s: %d\n", graph->name, graph->vc);
    for (int i = 0; i < graph->vc; i++)
    {
        printf("Node: %d - Adjacent Nodes: ", graph->node[i]->nodeNumber);
        const char *pad = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < graph->node[i]->adjNum; j++)
        {
            printf("%s%d", pad, graph->node[i]->adjacent[j]->nodeNumber);
            pad = ", ";
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    const char *filename = "data";
    if (argc == 2)
        filename = argv[1];
    Graph *graph = readGraphFromTxt(filename);
    if (graph != 0)
    {
        printAllGraphNodeNumber(graph);
        freeGraph(graph);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Data

A copy of what was supplied in the question:

```
one
AM
10
0100010011
1000110100
0000100001
0000000010
0110000100
1100000001
0000000001
0100100010
1001000101
1010011010
```

#### Output

```
Nodes in the graph one: 10
Node: 0 - Adjacent Nodes: 1, 5, 8, 9
Node: 1 - Adjacent Nodes: 0, 4, 5, 7
Node: 2 - Adjacent Nodes: 4, 9
Node: 3 - Adjacent Nodes: 8
Node: 4 - Adjacent Nodes: 1, 2, 7
Node: 5 - Adjacent Nodes: 0, 1, 9
Node: 6 - Adjacent Nodes: 9
Node: 7 - Adjacent Nodes: 1, 4, 8
Node: 8 - Adjacent Nodes: 0, 3, 7, 9
Node: 9 - Adjacent Nodes: 0, 2, 5, 6, 8
```

Having upgraded to macOS High Sierra 10.13, I am (once again) without Valgrind.  However, several other tools reassure me that this is probably correct.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by removing the piece of code commented as **free each adjacent node** in the function **freeGraph()**. Resulting code looks like:

```
void freeGraph(_GRAPH_ *graph){
    // free graph
    for (int i=0; i<graph->vc; i++) {
        // free each node data
        printf("\nLoop: %d\n", i);
            // free each adjacent node
            /*
        for (int k=0; k<graph->node[i]->adjNum; k++){
            if(graph->node[i]->adjacent[k]!=NULL){
                free(graph->node[i]->adjacent[k]);
            }
        }*/
        if(graph->node[i]->adjacent!=NULL) {
            free(graph->node[i]->adjacent);
        }
        free(graph->node[i]);
    }
    free(graph->node);
    for(int i=0; i<graph->vc; i++)
        if(graph->AM[i]!=NULL) free(graph->AM[i]);
    free(graph->AM);
    free(graph->name);
    // commenting this out : because this is not dynamically allocated 
    //    free(graph);
}
```

The reason why I did this is because `graph->node[i]->adjacent[k]` are the pointers to different nodes of the graph which are going to be freed at last by `free(graph->node[i])`.

I checked using **Valgrind**, its working perfectly. Stats showing a clean bill of health. All allocations are freed. I think I am good to go.

PS: I still don't think its an optimal solution. But this is how I solved my problem. Hope anybody else can provide a better answer.

Comment: Your solution is correct. The only other genwric way to free an arbitrary graph is ro rely on garbage collection, which isn't avalilable by default in C.

Comment: @n.m. — 'ro' --> 'to' if you're quick.